# Copy rails projects from one machine to another(Github issue)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

I’m new to rails and github and found such problem. I have cloned two projects to my first machine(work there sometime – made branches and all this stuff) and now I need to move these projects to my another machine – and I don’t know how to do it. I know that I can again clone this projects on my second machine but it didn’t save my branches. Can somebody give me any advices. Thanks for the help

P.s. Can I simply copy my projects folders from one machine on flashdrive and paste it to another machine?

Answer (score 2):

yes you can simply copy that on flashdrive and paste it to another machine

Comment: Do you know, shoud I again setup my database for my projects on my second machine or after copying everything will work without second setup?

Comment: if you have database in sqlite3 with in your project under db foldr than i think it will not be needed otherwise you have to again setup that but in rails you do not have to much worried about that as all you have to do rake db:create and rake db:migrate :)

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to accomplish this using the **--bare** and **--mirror** tags with **git clone**

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/repository-to-mirror.git
# Make a bare mirrored clone of the repository

cd repository-to-mirror.git
git remote set-url --push origin https://github.com/exampleuser/mirrored
# Set the push location to your mirror
```

See this article form github for more info:

https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository

And as @NitinJ said, from there you just run

```
rake db:create:all (or just enter the selected db's you want to create)
rake db:migrate
```